# Highcharts treemap link legends

Tags: highcharts

I would like to link a pair of areas to a legend in highcharts treemap so that clicking on the legend turns both the area on/off.

For example, in this fiddle, if I click 'America' in the legend I would like it to turn off both the areas covering 'America' & similarly to do with 'Australia'.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LokeshKG/xpvt214o/953169/).

```
$(function() {
var H = Highcharts;

H.addEvent(H.Legend, 'afterGetAllItems', function(e) {
    e.allItems.splice(1, 2);
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'treemap'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (event) {
                    alert('Done');
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{

        data: [{
            'name': 'Americas',
            'value': 52976,
            'color': 'rgba(47,126,216,1)'
        }, {
            'name': 'Australia',
            'value': 41219,
            'color': 'rgba(13,35,58,1)'
        }, {
            'name': 'Americas',
            'value': 52976,
            'color': 'rgba(47,126,216,1)'
        }, {
            'name': 'Australia',
            'value': 41219,
            'color': 'rgba(13,35,58,1)'
        }],
        legendType: 'point',
        showInLegend: true
    }]


});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use point `legendItemClick` event and internal `setVisible` method:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function(event) {
                        var points = this.series.points;

                        points.forEach(function(p) {
                            if (this !== p && this.name === p.name) {
                                p.setVisible(!this.visible, true);
                            }
                        }, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k4o8q6du/

Comment: Thanks this works! Anyway is it possible to achieve same with different charts. I have two identical charts with same legends & I want to link the legend click actions between the charts if the node has same name. Consider above example instead of duplicate 'America' & 'Australia' in the same chart, I have 2 different charts with same 'America' & 'Australia' node & Clicking on 'America' legend should ON/OFF the node in both the charts.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Please see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1yhmt3s0/